# rails decimal precision and scale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have about 30 tables in a rails app and there are about 6 tables for which I would like to change the precision and scale of some of the decimal columns.  How do you go about doing that for already existing columns?  Do you need to do each new migration separately, or can they all be done at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, :type
```

will update the column's type.

Ref: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column

Comment: If the :type isn't changing, just :precision and :scale, this does not work.