# Rails: Cannot add :precision or :scale options with change_column in a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, decimal, precision, scale

This seems to have been asked before: [rails decimal precision and scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402547/rails-decimal-precision-and-scale)

But when running a `change_column` migration for `:precision` or `:scale` they don't actually affect the schema or database, but `db:migrate` runs without errors.

My migration file looks like this:

```
class ChangePrecisionAndScaleOfPaybackPeriodInTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :tags, :payback_period, :decimal, { :scale => 3, :precision => 10 }
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :tags, :payback_period, :decimal
  end
end
```

But my schema (and the data) remains as:

```
t.decimal  "payback_period"
```

Anybody else have this issue?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Does Not Work for SQLite3

For this simple test app that I'm running I have SQLite3 setup. Apparently, **SQLite3 doesn't rely on column type declarations** and is more dynamic, looking at the column's content instead - as was stumbled upon here:

[Modify a Column's Type in sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083543/modify-a-columns-type-in-sqlite3)

I haven't tested it but I'm sure that's why the schema wasn't being changed, because `change_column` doesn't translate to anything in SQLite3.

Thanks for the replies guys.

Answer (score 36):

Had a related (but not same) problem. I was just changing scale, so when changing the :scale you need the full line:

```
change_column :something, :weight, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
```

omitting :decimal (which it already was) and :precision (which already was 10) will cause the migration to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Delete and regenerate `db\schema.rb` file.

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Comment: No joy, still shows same thing. Plus, using the app shows that the migration options have had no effect.

Comment: I ran the same script and `schema.rb` file changed accordingly.

Comment: I tried it again and still nothing. Perhaps having to do with content already in the database?

Answer (score 0):

A hack, but it should get you where you need to go:

```
class ChangePrecisionAndScaleOfPaybackPeriodInTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE tags CHANGE payback_period DECIMAL(3,10)"
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :tags, :payback_period, :decimal
  end
end
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but this didn't work either. I went rooting around trying to find proper syntax for altering a column type in sqlite3 and found there is no way. I'm sure with mysql or another db, I wouldn't even have a problem. Posting an answer here.